# How to get a count of values in field using calculated columns

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a calculated column and would like to get a count of all the occurrences of "true".
So the first row shudl return 3 and the next 2 etc..
Can this be achieved using calculated columns

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Is all column are single line of text column or Boolean(yes/no) columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below formula will be help you to calculate occurrences of "true". In below formula all columns(01 to 05) are text columns. If you are using other column type then need to update formula

`=IF(LOWER([Column01])="true", 1, 0)+IF(LOWER([Column02])="true", 1, 0)+IF(LOWER([Column03])="true", 1, 0)+IF(LOWER([Column04])="true", 1, 0)+IF(LOWER([Column05])="true", 1, 0)`

please refer below screenshot

[image]